# How to open add contact page in android from a mobile browser

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-chrome

I want to give the users the ability to add contacts directly from my website. I know we cant access contact book from the browser , but I couldn't find any resources as to how to redirect users to a prefilled add contact page.

I came across chrome intents `https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents` but not sure how to use them for contacts.

Comment: Did you find any working solution?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the official documentation you've linked to is missing another item in the intent parts `type`.

The intent you want to call in Java would be:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.ACTION);
intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
```

If we translate the constants to literals, that would be:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.INSERT");
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/contact");
```

If we now translate that to chrome's Android intent scheme, that would be:

```
var url = "intent:#Intent;action=android.intent.action.INSERT;type=vnd.android.cursor.dir/contact;end"
```

Note that you must have a user interaction in order for Chrome on Android to call this intent, so it needs to be in a button or similar to make it work (typing directly to the address bar will not work as well)